# Browsers getting only greater media query while ignoring the smaller width one

Tags: css

So basically I have this simple code:

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
#video-background{height:25vh;width:100%}
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px){
#video-background{height:76vh;width:100%}
}
```

And every time I load the html in no matter which browser, they ignore the first query and use the second one (min-width:768px), even when the screen size is smaller than 768px. I've tried to put the smaller query before and after the other, and nothing seems to work.

Comment: Do you have metadata for viewport? Can you see in console that one of rule is disabled/overwritten?

Comment: please write min-width code first then max width media query code. Hope this helps. Happy coding :)

Comment: try css like `border` or `background` see if this works

Comment: @Justinas I don't have metadata, but I don't get any overwritten or disabled rule in console. When I remove the min-width query, it simply doesn't get the 767px and applies auto height. So I guess the problem is there, but I can't see where.

Comment: @PratikshaKale That's the way I firstly coded the css, but still no results.

Comment: @eladBA I tried and it doesn't seem to work

Comment: You need to have viewport metadata for media queries to work properly: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag/

Comment: Okay, it worked! I just never needed that, but from now on, I'll sure be using it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As @Justinas said:

> You need to have viewport metadata for media queries to work properly:

[Responsive meta tag](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/html/responsive-meta-tag)

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working fine.

I think you have not written meta tag -

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Please write this meta tag in your header.